# get xml node value and add 1 then save it again into the xml file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Am new at using xml .
I have a simple xml file 'rate.xml' contains that :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<person>

<rate id="rate_this">
1
</rate>

</person>
```

all I want to do is a php script gets the value of rate tag and adds 1 to it 
(i.e. 1+1 = 2) then updates the rate tag value to the new result.
I tried this script but it's not working :

```
<?php
$person = simplexml_load_file('rate.xml');
$rateNode = $person->getElementsByAttribute("id"); 
$xmlType = $rateNode->getElementsByTagName( "rate" );
$valueType = $xmlType->item(0)->nodeValue;  
$newValue = $valueType + 1 ;
$person->rate->nodevalue = $newValue;
?>
```

implementation will be so helpful :)

Comment: You seem to be attempting to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) methods with a [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) object.

Comment: Yes , but it's getting me errors that these methods are undefined !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that will do the job for you:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents ('file.xml')); // loads your xml
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nlist = $xpath->query("//person/rate[@id='rate_this']");
$node = $nlist->item(0);
$newval = trim($node->nodeValue)+1;
$node->nodeValue = $newval;
file_put_contents ('out.xml', $doc->saveXML());
```

#### Your file out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<person>

<rate id="rate_this">2</rate>

</person>
```

Comment: Awesome !! it worked :)
but i dunn get the use of trim function ; what is it for ?

Comment: trim is used to remove spaces and newlines around nodeValue.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
<?php
$domelement = dom_import_simplexml(simplexml_load_file('rate.xml'));
$person = $domelement->ownerDocument;
$xmlNodes = $person->getElementsByTagName( "rate" );
$valueType = $xmlNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;  
$newValue = $valueType + 1 ;
$xmlNodes->item(0)->nodeValue = $newValue;
echo($person->saveXML());
?>
```

I have edited the code. Please note that getElementsByAttribute is not a valid method, and is unnecessary here. [Here](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/2qx-n8p) is an example of this code in action.

Alternatively, you can use Xpath to find elements by their attributes:

```
<?php
$sxml = simplexml_load_file('rate.xml');
$searcharray = $sxml->xpath("//*[@id='rate_this']");
$rate = $searcharray[0];
$value = $rate[0];
$newValue = intval($value) + 1 ;
$rate[0] = $newValue;
echo($sxml->asXML());
?>
```

[Here](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/tai-ucg) is an example of that. The output is the same.

There is no difference between these two examples. They have exactly the same result, and using Xpath will still not automatically save your output to a file. If you want to save your output to a file, use something like this instead of echoing the output:

```
$f = fopen("rate.xml", "w");
fwrite($f, $sxml->asXML());
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Unfortunately , it's giving the same error :  Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementsByAttribute()

Comment: Well yes, that method isn't actually defined for either DOMDocument or simplexml. I should have taken a closer look at your code. I will edit in a bit.

Comment: it's changing in the element value but not saving it instead of the first value ?!

Comment: The value inside the rate element is being changed to 2. The output of this example (minus whitespace) is `<person><rate id="rate_this">2</rate></person>`. Do you mean the changed value is not reflected in your file?

Comment: Yes it was , but when i used Xpath it's reflected successfully